# How to move programatically to on other ion-tab

Tags: ionic-framework

I have these tabs at the bottom of my app

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="cloud-upload"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"> . </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

This works, if I click on the About tab, it navigates to that page and highlights that tab in the footer on which I just clicked.

But now I would like to have a button in my Home component which activates (moves to) the 'About' tab the same way as I just described above. At first this seems easy, something like

```
gotoAbout(): void {
    this.navCtrl.push(AboutPage)
    // or this.navCtrl.setRoot(AboutPage)
}
```

The `this.navCtrl.push` creates a back button in the header, which is not what I want, I don't need a stack, I simply want to go to the other tab.

So the `this.navCtrl.setRoot(AboutPage)` seems to work better, but none of them highlight the tab in the footer. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/#usage) on this. There's a `select` method ;)

Comment: I see it now, it was hidden in the `parent` object :) Thanks a lot!